# Differentiating between internal HDDs and external HDDs in Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, powershell, bitlocker

In Windows, is there a command/function/cmdlet which I can call to help me differentiate between an internal (fixed) HDD and an external (portable) USB HDD?

PowerShell commands, such as **Get-Volume**, state that my plugged in USB HDD is "Fixed".

Context: I am trying to write a BitLocker script which encrypts all internal hard drives, but does not encrypt removable/portable USB hard drives.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible to achieve reliably because Windows cannot distinguish between the two. Whether your USB HDD is shown as "fixed" depends entirely on the disk and the driver, there is nothing you can do about it. Any disk can identify as internal or external regardless of true state. Though you could use identification of a 'USB' disk as a rough workaround.

Comment: I had a feeling this may be the case. Using the notion of being connected to USB could work? If I could determine storage devices connected via USB then I could ignore those in the encryption script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-PhysicalDisk` includes the property `BusType` that might be something you can use. I am not sure what all the possible values returned could be, but I have two USB drives attached to my laptop, along with the local drive. This is the output I get:
`Get-PhysicalDisk | select FriendlyName, BusType`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. I have gone ahead and used `BusType` for my script.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Property * | Where {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

- Unknown (0)
- No Root Directory (1)
- Removable Disk (2)
- Local Disk (3)
- Network Drive (4)
- Compact Disc (5)
- RAM Disk (6)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the portable HDD still shows as a local disk.

Comment: Sorry - didn't have an external disk to hand to try so i mounted a virtual DVD, network drive etc and wittled down as much as I could.

Comment: No worries. I'm still no further. If you have any further suggestions please say.